# Can I replace domain in the address of WooCommerce downloadable files for all products?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

The addresses of the downloadable files of my woocommerce products are as follows
**https://my-site.com**/folder01/file00987.zip

Can I change the addresses for all my 2500 products as follows?
**https://replace-site.com**/folder01/file00987.zip

Actually, I just want to replace the domain from all File addresses

I couldn't find a way to do this
Is it possible to do this with a function in WordPress or a command in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can update in mysql -

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = replace(comment_content , 'old_domain.com', 'newdomain.com');
```

After that save permalink as well

Comment: Thanks.
 Where should I put this code?
 in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/nd2FX53-N4lp
you can see this option in PHPMYADMIN database section. make sure change your domain name and table name.